# A confusion regarding friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

Suppose there is a block which is being pulled by two forces A,B in opposite direction(as shown in figure).
If we have no information regarding the forces $A$ and $B$, can we tell whether there is any friction?

For example if $A = B$ then there will be no friction but if $A > B$ or $B > A$ then there will be friction.

[image]

Comment: There is friction and it depends on the weight of the object

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. You do not need to preface questions with extraneous information about this being your first question, etc. We can see that from your profile if we care to (in general whether or not you've asked questions before doesn't matter at all anyway). Also, note that this site supports TeX style math. I edited your question to use it. Please look at the source (hit the edit button) to see how it works. Finally, please use punctuation: put a question mark at the end of questions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of friction $f_s \leq \mu_sN$ for static friction and $f_k = \mu_kN$ for kinetic friction. So the friction is balanced by the difference between A and B until $F = \left|A-B\right| = f_s$ at which point we get an acceleration of the block due to the fact that ususally $\mu_s > \mu_k$ which are dimensionless constants which depend on the surfaces.  Note, $N$ is a force vector with the same magnitude as $mg$ but opposite direction (up instead of down), where $m$ is the mass of the block and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity.  So friction is only proportional to the weight of the block and not to the sliding speed or area of contact.

Answer (score 1):

If you measure the box's acceleration $a$, then it must be the case that
$$
m a = F_\text{fric} + F_A - F_B \quad \Rightarrow \quad F_\text{fric} = m a - F_A + F_B.
$$
In particular, in the special case where the box is no accelerating (i.e., it's at rest or moving with a constant velocity), then the frictional force will be zero if and only if $F_A = F_B$.  More generally, though, you would need to know the magnitude of the block's acceleration to determine whether there is a frictional force present or not.

Note that this method is independent of whether the frictional force is static or kinetic.  (Presumably it would be kinetic in the case where $a \neq 0$, but the case $a = 0$ could be either one.)